# What are the possible ways to create a list containing 50 ones in python?

Tags: python, list

What are the various ways in which we can create a list containing 50 one's using python?

Comment: My favourite way: `from collections import OrderedDict;
exec("".join(map(chr,[int("".join(str(OrderedDict([(':)', 0),
             (':D', 1),
             (':P', 2),
             (':S', 3),
             (':(', 4),
             ('=)', 5),
             ('=/', 6),
             (':/', 7),
             (':{', 8),
             (';)', 9)])[i]) for i in x.split())) for x in
":D :D :P  :D :D :(  :D :) =)  :D :D :)  :D :D =/  :( :)  ;) :D  :( ;) \
 ;) :S  :( :P  =) :S  :( :{  :( :D  :D :)"
.split("  ")])))` https://pastebin.com/YWNiV2Fy

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here are hundreds of ways to do this. I think one of the simplest ones is using `list comprehension`, like:

```
ones = [1 for i in range(50)]
```

Comment: I would say that might be the second simplest.

Comment: Which one is the first?

Comment: That would be `[1]*50`

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> a = [1]*50
>>> a
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>>
```

```
>>> a = [1 for _ in range(50)]
>>> a
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>>
```